# Generating nodes at joining points

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-join, proximity, nodes

I have road network (lines) and points (Address) . With the help of `closestSegmentWithContext function`, I join points to nearest lines in QGIS. Is there a way to to generate a nodes at every joining point as I have drawn manually in below figure for demonstration?

[image]

The code for joining line segements to nearest points is given below and shape files are available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-DKB4bGSYzgrP2Za2FWdmO-tBJBsU1oT?usp=sharing):

```
roadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('TR_ROAD')[0]
addrlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ADDRESS')[0]

#List all features
adresses = [f for f in addrlyr.getFeatures()]
roads = [f for f in roadlyr.getFeatures()] 

#Create empty vector layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(roadlyr.crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

for adress in adresses:
    a = min([road.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(adress.geometry().asPoint()) for road in roads], key=lambda x: x[0]) #For each road find closest address
    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(adress.geometry().asPoint()), QgsPoint(a[1])])
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(gLine)
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```